# ! LaTeX Error: Command \item invalid in math mode. In- l.367 \item {\bf Large Product Catalog:}\\ You can almost get everything on

Tags: macros, errors

```
\subsection{FEATURES: }

\begin{itemize}
\item {\bf Amazon Prime:}\\ This is a big customer acquisition tool for Amazon. Once registered a customer will keep coming back to Amazon. The customer has invested $79 to subscribe to a service. His goal is to derive maximum value of the service. This results in more sales for Amazon.
\item {\bf Large  Product Catalog:}\\ You can almost get everything on Amazon. (Not everything but one of the largest catalog on the Internet").
\item {\bf Frequently Bought Together:}\\ This is a feature where people are given product suggestions based on what they are interested in. The quality of suggestions ensure that only relevant product suggestions are made.
\item {\bf Search:}\\ People are not lost in the large catalog of products and are provided with good search results.
\item {\bf Product Reviews by Customers: }\\ Reviews helps people make decisions. An additional service that Amazon provides and makes it easier for customers to select a product.
\item {\bf Amazon 1 click Ordering : }\\ Conversions are crucial in the payment process. 1-click ensures there are no drop offs there.
\item {\bf Search Results:  }\\ Amazon ranks high in search results for various reasons. It has many inbound links, has quality content, good product description, almost everything about the product.
\item {\bf Excellent Customer Service: }\\ Amazon is no.1 in customer service. But Will This Lead To Sustainable Loyalty?, is not sure.
\item {\bf Excellent Supply Chain:}\\ Amazon invests heavily in its Supply Chain and is considered one of the best Supply Chains in the world.
\item {\bf Market Place:}\\ I am unsure about the percentage impact on sales, but this is definitely a feature that helps increase sales.
\item {\bf Affliate Marketing:}\\ It  is a commission based program. The registered user in affliate program will be given a unique code along with the site links, so if someone purchases from amazon using the link, then a commission of some percetage of the cost of the product will be credited to the registered affliate user. 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *full* compilable code, reproducing your problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome. `$` starts inline  math mode, to actually print a dollar sign, use `\$`.

Answer (score 8):

That would be caused by the dollar sign you have in the first item. Single dollar signs are used to delimit inline math mode, i.e. `text $math$ more text`. To actually print a dollar sign, use `\$`.

In addition, note that `\bf` has been deprecated for nearly 25 years now, use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{bold text}` instead. That said though, I would consider using a `description` list for this, in which `\item[Foo]` gives `Foo` printed in bold. You can use the features of the `enumitem` package to customize the looks, saving you the trouble of a lot of manual markup.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\subsection{FEATURES:}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=1em,format=\textbullet~]
\item[Amazon Prime:]
This is a big customer acquisition tool for Amazon. Once registered a customer will keep coming back to Amazon. The customer has invested \$79 to subscribe to a service. His goal is to derive maximum value of the service. This results in more sales for Amazon.
\item[Large  Product Catalog:]
You can almost get everything on Amazon. (Not everything but one of the largest catalog on the Internet").
\item[Frequently Bought Together:]
This is a feature where people are given product suggestions based on what they are interested in. The quality of suggestions ensure that only relevant product suggestions are made.
\item[Search:]
People are not lost in the large catalog of products and are provided with good search results.
\item[Product Reviews by Customers:]
Reviews helps people make decisions. An additional service that Amazon provides and makes it easier for customers to select a product.
\item[Amazon 1 click Ordering:]
Conversions are crucial in the payment process. 1-click ensures there are no drop offs there.
\item[Search Results:]
Amazon ranks high in search results for various reasons. It has many inbound links, has quality content, good product description, almost everything about the product.
\item[Excellent Customer Service:]
Amazon is no.1 in customer service. But Will This Lead To Sustainable Loyalty?, is not sure.
\item[Excellent Supply Chain:]
Amazon invests heavily in its Supply Chain and is considered one of the best Supply Chains in the world.
\item[Market Place:]
I am unsure about the percentage impact on sales, but this is definitely a feature that helps increase sales.
\item[Affliate Marketing:]
It  is a commission based program. The registered user in affliate program will be given a unique code along with the site links, so if someone purchases from amazon using the link, then a commission of some percetage of the cost of the product will be credited to the registered affliate user. 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Personally I wouldn't even use the colons there as the formatting already provides the distinction between item "header"/body.